# Fixed length rows in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have to create a RecyclerView(Trying to achieve listView using RecyclerView) with user Image and Name. I pull the users dynamically. So I don’t know the user count. I have to list the users in recycler view with user profile image and user name. I tried below layout for RecyclerView item. But I could not get the perfect view. It adjusts the width of ImageView and TextView correctly but I could not bring in equally fixed height of the row. Also I am trying to fix the size of the image view. Is it possible for me to fix the size of an image view without using dp so that its flexible for various screen sizes?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/user"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/portrait"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_weight="3" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/nameLabel"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:paddingTop="24dp"
        android:paddingBottom="24dp"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:textSize="24sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Listview or RecycleView? both are not same.

Comment: It is Recyclerview. Trying Listview with recycler view

Comment: You can't "try ListView with RecyclerView".  They are two different things.  You should be preferring to use RecyclerView for showing lists of items.

Comment: Actually I meant the same. I am trying to achieve list view from recycler view. OnCreateView of RecyclerView will use this layout to inflate the items within recycler view